# Python If/else confusion

Tags: python, if-statement

So I have a problem with my game, I copy-pasted a part from it here. As you can see, this code shall print Yeah only if the first x elements of the list position are smaller than 7 and if all the rest elements are bigger than 7 and the final element is 0. However as you can see on the example, 0 is not the last element in the list, but I get the printing Yeah. Why is it? Thank you!

```
position=[3,6,4,2,5,0,10,12,7,8]
where=1
a=1
for i in range(6-where):
    if position[i]<7 and position[i]!=0:
        pass
    else:
        a=0
print(a)
for i in range(6-where,-1):
    if position[i]>6 and position[-1]==0:
        pass
    else:
        a=0
print(a)
print(position[-1])
if a==1:
    print("Yeah")
```

Comment: It should be noted that `range(6-where,-1)` is an empty range. If you want to count backwards, you need `range(6-where,-1, -1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the option of putting this in a function? If so, early exits are your friend:

```
def is_winner(nums, middle):
    # The last number must be a zero
    if nums[-1] != 0:
        return False

    # All of the starting numbers must be less than 7
    if not all(num < 7 for num in nums[:middle]):
        return False

    # All of the ending numbers must be at least 7
    if not all(num >= 7 for num in nums[middle:-1]):
        return False

    # If all of those are OK, then we've succeeded
    return True


# This will print False because it doesn't end in 0.
position = [3, 6, 4, 2, 5, 0, 10, 12, 7, 8]
print(is_winner(position, 6))

# This will print True because it meets the requirements.
position = [3, 6, 4, 2, 5, 0, 10, 12, 7, 8, 0]
print(is_winner(position, 6))

# This will print False because a number in the first part is greater than 7
position = [3, 6, 4, 2, 5, 0, 10, 12, 7, 8, 0]
print(is_winner(position, 7))

# This will print False because a number in the second part is not at least 7
position = [3, 6, 4, 2, 5, 0, 10, 12, 7, 8, 0]
print(is_winner(position, 5))
```

See how the function can be very simple and readable? At each step, you're stopping if the requirements aren't met. You don't have to track state or anything; you just return False. If you reach the end of the function and haven't failed any tests, then ta-da! You're successful and can return True.

BTW, according to your example, the second requirement should be `x >= 7`, not `x > 7`. If that's not right, update the code and examples to match.

Answer (score 0):

In your first if statement, you have position[i] instead of position[-1].

Here is some improved, simpler code as well:

```
position=[3,6,4,2,5,0,10,12,7,8]
x = 5
valid_list = True
for i in range(x):
    if position[i] >= 7 or position[i] == 0:
        valid_list = False

for i in range(len(position) - x - 1):
    if position[x + i] < 7 or position[i] == 0:
        valid_list = False
        
if valid_list and position[-1] == 0:
    print('Yeah')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a bit entangled. First of all, use a boolean value and a proper name for `a`. For example `listValid = True`. But it is also possible without it.

```
position=[3,6,4,2,5,0,10,12,7,8]
splitIndex = 6 - 1
if all([value < 7 for value in position[:splitIndex]]):
     if all([value > 6 for value in position[splitIndex:-1]]):
          if position[-1] == 0:
               print("Yeah")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two errors in your code:
First as pointed by  https://stackoverflow.com/users/10788239/arkleseisure
The line in the first *if* statement must be
`if position[i]<7 and position[-1]!=0:`, but you have written
`... and position[i]!=0`
Secondly your second for loop doesnt get executed because its iterator is `range(6-where,-1)`, the range function by default gives an ascending iterator, so in your case the iterator is empty. For a descending list, add a *step* argument to *range* func and use `range(6-where, -1, -1)`.
Here the last *-1* is the step size for *range* function